# How to deal with not a function error in dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I am getting `not a function error` for my `callChart` Function in dojo. I am developing a website, which uses **excanvas** to paint some charts on the browser.

On page load I am having one Ajax call which fetches some database values and passes them to `callChart:function()`, this callChart function call excanvas for charting. But here I am getting `callChart is not a function`.

**Code snippet is like below:**

onload I am having executing

```
 drawChart : function(){     
     this.chart(true);     
 },

chart: function(flag){
 dojo.xhrPost( {
 url : "/charting.html", 
 load : function(data){
          loadChart(data);
},
 error : function(error){
         console.error(" occured while fetch chart" );
    }
  } );
```

And in success callback method

```
loadChart : function(response){
        this.callChart(response);

},
```

and this is my callChart,

```
callChart:function(chartData){
----
----
},
```

When I am calling this.callChart(response), I am getting firebug error "`this.callChart(response) is not a function`" .

Any help, guidance or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of `this` when the `callChart` call occurs?

Comment: I am very new to dojo. I tried to inspect "this" in firebug and there I saw list of many functions. But that list does not include "callChart".. So does it mean that its out of scope of "this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "this" is the callback mechanism (dojo.Deferred). Use dojo.hitch to fix the context:

```
chart: function(flag){
 dojo.xhrPost( {
 url : "/charting.html", 
 load : dojo.hitch(this, function(data){ // changed this line
          this.loadChart(data); // added "this"
 }); // close paran
}
```

Comment: After adding dojo.hitch, it will allow to run the "callChart" in the same context?

Comment: Yes, it will point to the same object as that of chart() and callChart().

Comment: dojo.hitch will fix, if there is a problem in calling loadChart(), but in my case problem is in calling callChart() which is in the loadChart(). I am getting problem in calling "callChart()".

Comment: I'm assuming callChart is in the same object, because you otherwise are not showing where it is. If it's in another object, call it via that object.